# Can a Select Count(*) Affect Writes in Cassandra

Tags: count, cassandra, cql

I experienced a scenario where a select count(*) on a table every minute (yes, this should definitely be avoided) caused a huge increase in Cassandra writes to around 150K writes per second.

Can anyone explain this weird behavior? Why would a Select query significantly increase write count in Cassandra?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit strange. I don't see any point on why C* should increase its write counts. How did you measure that?

Comment: I can't imagine a reason this would happen. Much more likely there is another process doing things ...

Comment: Is it possible to clarify the term "writes" please? Just to differentiate between disk writes, and Cassandra mutations. Are you seeing write requests backing up in nodetool tpstats, and dropped mutations? Or are you observing disk queueing? 150K mutations per second is a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check

`org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ReadRepair,name=RepairedBackground`

and

`org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ReadRepair,name=RepairedBlocking`

metrics you can see if its read repairs sending mutations. Perhaps reading all the data to service the count(*) is causing a lot of read repairs if your data is inconsistent. If thats the case lowering the `read_repair_chance` and `dclocal_read_repair_chance` on the table (`ALTER TABLE`) could reduce load.

Other likely possibilities are:

- You have tracing enabled (either globally or on the table) as some %.
- Or if you use DSE and you have slow query's enabled.

Comment: Thanks Chris!
Cassandra did performed multiple read repairs during those select queries and this is most likely the root cause for the issue I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation could be found in [the write path of an update](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_write_update_c.html):

> During a write , Cassandra adds each new row to the database without checking on whether a duplicate record exists. This policy makes it possible that many versions of the same row may exist in the database.

Then

> Most Cassandra installations store replicas of each row on two or more nodes. Each node performs compaction independently. This means that even though out-of-date versions of a row have been dropped from one node, they may still exist on another node.

And finally:

> This is why Cassandra performs another round of comparisons during a read process. When a client requests data with a particular primary key, Cassandra retrieves many versions of the row from one or more replicas.